# Getting null MenuItem View from a Custom Toolbar

Tags: android, android-studio, android-actionbar, android-view, android-toolbar

I have read a lot of similar topics but none of the solutions works to me. I'm getting the MenuItem normaly, but when i try to get its view, I get a *null* view. I already tried put the code in the **onPrepareOptionsMenu**, get the view with **MenuItemCompat**, and other sutff.

activity_main.xml, where is the toolbar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    ...
    tools:context=".activities.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            android:elevation="4dp"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    ...
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

menu_main.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".activities.MainActivity">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_location"
        android:orderInCategory="0"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_map"
        android:title="Localização"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

     ...
</menu>
```

onCreate method

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    ...
}
```

onCreateOptionsMenu method

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_location);  // here is fine, found the item
    View view = menuItem.getActionView();  // here is null

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Familiarize yourself with what a [ActionView](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/action-views.html) really is.

Just by assigning `menuItem`, you receive all the attributes about it, including the title, "Localização."

If you're trying to get the result of click "action_location," then [`onOptionsItemSelected`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onOptionsItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem)) may be the method call you need.